# Set width and height of various views programmatically in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, view

For an app i have an activity with various views and I need them all to be square, have the exact same height and width and occupy all together a specified portion of the screen. Therefore, I need to set the width and height programmatically, which seems to work with

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = newWidth;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

However, with many views this is pretty tedious, is there a way to set all heights and widths at once as they are all uniform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course. 1. If you use old style than: Just put all of the views inside the container like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. All children vuews should have width set to match_parent. Than change the params dynamically once / just for the container. 2. If you use ConstraintLayout , dependencies can do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that this is possible, however, I thought more about something like setting the dimensions in a dimens file and change that (although I already know that this does not seem to work...)

Comment: If you are searching for sth like this: it doesn't exist.